# Websocket running query every minute in mssqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server, websocket, sql-server-2014

I'm using websocket from C#. But my application slowed. Then I search for reason. And, we find below query from database log. This query (with different guid) worked 75 times in 1 hour. And every query takes very long time. And I think that it's locking my database. What is this query? And why does it taking long time? And what does it mean "`begin conversation timer`"?

```
exec sp_executesql N'BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER (''20a12dae-6fe1-e811-80d7-7ca23e8b6dfb'') 
TIMEOUT = 120; WAITFOR(RECEIVE TOP (1) message_type_name, 
conversation_handle, cast(message_body AS XML) as message_body 
from [SqlQueryNotificationService-fe5c857f-d91d-4db0-b6c5-29313929031c])
, TIMEOUT @p2;',N'@p2 int',@p2=60000
```

Comment: How large is the database?  What version of SQL Server are you using (are you using express).  Is the database fragmented?

Comment: 5.000.000 row in my auditing table. My database have a lot of table more than 100.000.000 rows. My ms sql isn't express. @jdweng

Comment: What does this query mean? @jdweng

Comment: Compacting the DataBase may help speed up query.  I do not know how long it takes to cast the xml which may be the reason it is taking long. I would try running without the cast to determine how long it takes.The query is waiting for the first data from a queue (The RECEIVE).The data may coming at a slow rate which is the reason for the slow time.The timer is going to timeout is no message is received  from the queue.I think the data is coming from a IP address and using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you may be able to determine if the slow speed is due to messages coming at a slow rate.

Comment: Thanks a lot your reply @jdweng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query tries to get a message from [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-2017) queue. With [BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/begin-conversation-timer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it sets timeout of 2 minutes (120 seconds). If there is nothing in the queue, it will stop waiting for a message in 2 minutes. One possible explanation why your queries are slow, is because there are no messages in the corresponding queue and they wait for a new one to come, until it timed out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AndreyNikolov. I understood that, It doesn't matter if this query takes a long time. It isn't problem.  Am I write? Or should I change something? Because, I have no idea about background of websocket.

Comment: My scenario like this, my socket listen this query "select * from Students where studentType=1". And when row in this query changed, do something. @AndreyNikolov

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your question. You asked "what this mean" (Service Broker), "why it takes so long" (because the queue is empty) and "what is begin conversation timer" (setting the timeout value). What I can say is, that this isn't a performance issue. It is expected behavior. Should your change something? I think 2 minutes are pretty big timeout for waiting in your case. You are saying that it is called 75 times in 1 hour, which means every minute. So you may want to reduce the timeout to few seconds, but I'm not fully aware of your project.

Comment: `"exec sp_executesql N'BEGIN CONVERSATION.... "` query always take 60 second for 75 times. So, I thought that this will cause performance problem and lock my other real queries of my application. But I understood that your answer, this is expected behavior and there is no effect to performance. Thanks a lot again @AndreyNikolov

Comment: @AndreyNikolov , is there any way to avoid this stored proc. Because of this my query is taking 40 minutes in execution(which could normally execute in 1.5 minutes)? Any immediate help will be appreciated to avoid this.